# How to select the items that have an association with any user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a relation between User and Hobby, the relation in User is `has_and_belongs_to_many` and the one for Hobby is also `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

I'm trying to get the list of Hobbies that Users have chosen. For example if one user selected Soccer and another selected Basketball, I want to have a query that shows me "Soccer, Basketball". 
How can I do this join in a query? Right now I'm grabbing the hobbies for each User via `User.find(id).hobbies`

Comment: To clarify, you want to get a list of the hobbies that have been selected by any user?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to view the list of hobbies that the Users have chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could inner join hobbies with users to get all hobbies chosen by all users.

```
Hobby.joins(:users).uniq
```